# Error with input processing from requests module

Tags: python, api, request

I'm trying to do a basic request using DeepDream API and i get a error message, could anyone help?

Code:

```
import requests
        
start_url = 'xxxx'
r = requests.post(
 "https://api.deepai.org/api/deepdream",
 data={'image': start_url},
 headers={'api-key': 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'}
)

result = r.json(); print(result)
```

Terminal error:

```
{'err': 'error processing given inputs from request'}
```

Comment: try with `data=json.dumps({'image': start_url})` after importing `json`

Comment: Hey @KrishnaChaurasia it's returning the initial url, not the final one

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be on deepai server error.
I didn't resolve this yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).